# Check if a string date is a Monday

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form which has a textbox which users can pick from a datepicker and enter a date. I need to check if that selected date falls on a Monday.

My current code is below.

```
string dateInput = txtStartDate.Text;
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);
DayOfWeek today = dt.DayOfWeek;

if (today != DayOfWeek.Monday)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Day is not a monday");
}
```

When I run the form and select a date that is not on a Monday, no message is displayed. I'm not sure if I put this in javascript or a c# function and really not sure if the code is even correct. Any ideas and comments are appreciated.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` is used for console output, not windows forms or web forms. Depending on what stack you are using there are various ways to display messages and which one you choose depends on where you want the validation to take place. In a web app it is common to do basic validation in javascript and then again server side. You could also have a POST web method that returns an error result (badrequest + validation error) or maybe you want something in a web form like in the Submit handler and then write error text to a label... There are many ways to do this.

Comment: The looks like it would work, but I think we need more context.  Is this inside an `onload` event, or validation trigger, or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes, need more info. Is it a winforms, webforms or perhaps something decent like MVC ? :)

Comment: Which datepicker does it use? There are several to choose from, including ones based on jQuery.

Comment: First thing, I am using this in a web form and using a datepicker from HTML5 attributes. I think I am wanting a function that upon input validate whether the date lands on a Monday or not. It doesn't have to mean that the form is invalid but just a warning message. Not sure the best way but I think javascript might be the answer but just not sure how to do it the best way.

Comment: hey @PhilipHerman, did you get a chance to try my answer below, curious to know if it helped out

Answer (score 2):

Now, there are 2 ways to achieve this

- Invoking JS `<Script>` tag to display an alert
- Creating a Custom Alert Box and Show in your Code behind

**JavaScript alert**

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    public partial class CheckMonday : Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         CheckDate("Invalid Date");
       }

        private void CheckDate(string message)
        {

          string dateInput = txtStartDate.Text;
          DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);
          DayOfWeek today = dt.DayOfWeek;

          if (today != DayOfWeek.Monday)
          {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + message + "')</script>");
          }
         }
     }
```

**Custom AlertBox**

```
<div runat="server" id="AlertBox" class="alertBox" Visible="false">
  <div runat="server" id="AlertBoxMessage"></div>
  <button onclick="closeAlert.call(this, event)">Ok</button>
</div>
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    public partial class CheckMonday : Page
    {
       protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         CheckDate("Invalid Date");
       }

        private void CheckDate(string message)
        {

          string dateInput = txtStartDate.Text;
          DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);
          DayOfWeek today = dt.DayOfWeek;

          if (today != DayOfWeek.Monday)
          {
             MessageBoxShow(message);
          }
         }

         private void MessageBoxShow(string message)
         {
           this.AlertBoxMessage.InnerText = message;
           this.AlertBox.Visible = true;
         }
     }
```

Comment: I did try the js alert which works great. I ended up doing it a bit different but I have kept the code for future reference. Thanks a million for the ideas.

Comment: You're welcome, and could you also mark the answer as accepted as it would help serve as a reference for others in the community. Good day!!

Comment: Much obliged Sir!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to handle this using my original code minus the writeline in a function that is called on text changed. I did an auto post back and then used a hidden panel which held a warning message in it. If the validation was not correct, it would unhide the panel and show the message or else keep it hidden.

Don't know if that was the best option so if anyone else has a better or cleaner solution, I am up to trying it out. Thanks to all for your suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to something like:

```
string dateInput = txtStartDate.Text;
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateInput);
        DayOfWeek today = dt.DayOfWeek;

        if (today != DayOfWeek.Monday)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Day is not a monday");
        }
```

Comment: MessageBox is windows forms specific. The question is tagged with asp.net.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code

```
this.ShowMessage("Day is not a monday", "red");
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please also see [answer].